# Adober Reader 9 pdf review, comments stored in FBA sharepoint problems

Tags: adobe-reader, sharepoint, forms, review

---

### EDIT:

This issue below exists, however I think the REAL issue might actually be something to do with the fact that we are using a forms based authentication based sharepoint. I've discovered that if I return the next day to a pdf, the comments don't work, and the resources files all contain some html of the login page!!!

---

### The (old) issue:

In some cases, when a user opens a pdf that has comments stored in sharepoint, the comments and reviewers etc are not displayed, even clicking on Check for New Comments makes no difference.

---

### The reproduction:

I discovered that if the files stored in the users profile under Adobe/Acrobat/9.0/Synchronizer/resources (files called resource-[NUMBER]) are deleted somehow, then the next time you open the pdf, the comments will not be displayed and neither will the reviewers. Also, after you've deleted the files, and reopened the pdf, the resource files get recreated but are all 0Kb (empty).

---

### The workaround:

The fix for the issue seems to be to remove all files in the resources folder, then remove the pdf from the review using Track Reviews > Right click pdf > Click Remove Review from Tracker. Close the pdf, then reopen. This time, you will be asked to Connect to the review, and when it has done so, the comments etc reappear.

I can't be sure that the way I've reproduced this problem is exactly the same way that is causing the problem on clients machines, but it seems to produce the same problem.

Does anyone know of a fix for this? Adobe support recommended reinstalling Adobe Reader 9 :|, which is no use at all.

Answer (score 1):

I think we've gotten to the bottom of this issue ourselves.

The issue seems to be being caused by a combination of two things. There is a component of Adobe called the AdobeCollabSync which is a process that sits in the background and, by default, automatically synchronises comments with the server at regular intervals, *even* if you don’t have the pdf open. These are the comments etc that are stored in the resources folder that we’ve spoken about previously. What we’ve discovered is that when you log out of sharepoint (and/or your session times out on the server), the auto sync breaks. It attempts to retrieve the comments but it can’t because you are not logged in. And, unfortunately, it stays broken even if you do log back in – so as soon as your session times out on the server after you’ve logged out, you will never be able to see the comments again (unless you take the actions detailed previously – remove the pdf from the review, then reopen etc). I assume this problem does not happen with active directory, however I believe this is an issue caused by forms based authentication not being properly dealt with in the Adobe component.

We have discovered a resolution to this problem. This is on a per user basis, so all users need to do the following (Note my instructions are valid for Adobe Reader 9.0):

1)  If the user is in the situation where the comments are broken, then they need to take the steps detailed previously to remove the resources files, remove the pdf from the tracker, then reopen (see previous emails).
2)  Open Adobe Reader.
3)  Choose Edit > Preferences.
4)  Select Tracker in the list of Categories.
5)  Slide the “Automatically Check for New Comments and Form Data” slider to the right all the way to Never.
6)  Click Ok.